# inserting a new row, why cmax in system column is not zero

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Official Manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html

> **cmax** : The command identifier within the deleting transaction, or zero.

> **cmin** The command identifier (starting at zero) within the inserting transaction.

When I execute this:

```
begin;
insert into tags(tag) values ('jupyter');
insert into tags(tag) values ('windwos powershell');
insert into tags(tag) values ('command prompt');
commit;
```

and

```
SELECT tableoid,cmax,ctid,xmin,xmax,cmin, * FROM tags
```

The **Cmax** is 2 when the values is 'command prompt'. cmax value the same as cmin. But this is not deleting transaction. This is inserting transaction. So I understanding **cmin**. confused with **cmax**

Comment: They are actually the same thing. See here [Cmax](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAL454F1o56ZkfmsMasjxJHcOw%3DmwgowBu33JSkKWh2d31ARAUg%40mail.gmail.com)

Answer (score 2):

`cmin` and `cmax` are in reality the same. In the rare case that you insert and delete a tuple in the same transaction, a `combocid` is used. See `src/backend/utils/time/combocid.c`:

```
Before version 8.3, HeapTupleHeaderData had separate fields for cmin
and cmax.  To reduce the header size, cmin and cmax are now overlayed
in the same field in the header.  That usually works because you rarely
insert and delete a tuple in the same transaction, and we don't need
either field to remain valid after the originating transaction exits.
To make it work when the inserting transaction does delete the tuple,
we create a "combo" command ID and store that in the tuple header
instead of cmin and cmax. The combo command ID can be mapped to the
real cmin and cmax using a backend-private array, which is managed by
this module.

To allow reusing existing combo cids, we also keep a hash table that
maps cmin,cmax pairs to combo cids.  This keeps the data structure size
reasonable in most cases, since the number of unique pairs used by any
one transaction is likely to be small.

With a 32-bit combo command id we can represent 2^32 distinct cmin,cmax
combinations. In the most perverse case where each command deletes a tuple
generated by every previous command, the number of combo command ids
required for N commands is N*(N+1)/2.  That means that in the worst case,
that's enough for 92682 commands.  In practice, you'll run out of memory
and/or disk space way before you reach that limit.
```